# How to delete borders from facebook plugin

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-like

Hello I want to delete two borders from Facebook plugin but it doesn't work for me.
I tried by:

```
.pluginBoxDivider {
   border-top: none!important;
}
```

But it failed.

Picture of the borders:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
.pluginBoxDivider{border-top:0 !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure those are borders and no just `<hr>`? The left one looks wider than the content (the black box) which it should be covering.

Also, try setting:

```
border-top-style:none!important;
border-top-bottom:none!important;
```

Can you paste the whole code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UQ5zY/ here is code inspect element and u will see that is the border.

Comment: @user3669253: That's an `iframe`, it's impossible to remove the borders. The best you can do is to strategically place elements over the `iframe` to hide the borders (bad idea). I don't know if Facebook offers a non-`iframe` version, but I suspect they don't.

Comment: What I meant is if you can paste your normal code, the one you are working with. I'm not very good with iframes and for some reason it won't let me modify it's inner styles.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UQ5zY/1/  I pasted html5 version of this plugin now. I dont have other code than this it's just a plugin from Facebook page.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone searches and comes across this as I did. The Facebook page plugin is an iframe. An iframe is, pretty much, a window into a webpage that you do not control, so if it has borders, you can only paste over it on your own page via `position: absolute;`, but that's not recommended, as it will mess with responsiveness.